Error while confirm to the transaction in Solflare wallet for devnet
I'm developing a token mint program in the Solana chain using the @solana/spl-token Javascript library.
When I use the Phantom wallet, I'm able to confirm the transaction; But I'm unable to confirm the transaction when I use the Solflare wallet.
Under are the success image in the Phantom wallet and the fail image in the Solflare wallet.
this is fail image when using Solflare wallet
this is success image when using Phantom wallet
As you can see, when I use Solflare wallet I can't see the confirm button.
I think the reason is about devnet.
How can I solve this issue?

On Phantom wallet any thing goes, and that transaction will still failed, use on  either mainnet or devnet on both the wallet and you backend

It doesn't solve the issue.
